# ASN1 object identifier name

Tags: c++, c, openssl, asn.1

How to get object identifier name for X509_NAME_ENTRY?

My example:

```
X509_NAME *subject = X509_get_subject_name(certificate);

for (i = 0; i < X509_NAME_entry_count(subject); i++)
{
    e =X509_NAME_get_entry(subject, i);
    OBJ_obj2txt(id, 200, e->object, 1);
            //id like '2.5.4.6,2.5.4.6'

    value = ASN1_STRING_data(e->value);

}
```

For idendifier "2.5.4.6,2.5.4.6" I want obtain value "C", for "2.5.4.8,2.5.4.8" - "ST" and etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
char long_name[512];
i2t_ASN1_OBJECT(long_name, sizeof(long_name), e->object);
```

for what OpenSSL calls the "ln" and

```
const char *short_name;
int nid = OBJ_ln2nid(long_name);
short_name = OBJ_nid2sn(nid);
```

for the "sn".